# How to clear EditText form after a button's onClick intent passes

Tags: android, android-edittext

What I am trying to do is to have a simple sms application. The user puts their name and number in, and chooses to toggle a boolean box, and the enter button creates an intent to open up the built in sms and create a message according to the inputs.

What I'm having issues with is resetting the forms when I bring the application up again. Idealy I would like to have the entire application RESTART if you will, but Im not too sure how that works.

I was told to use:
    editText.setText("");
to bring the fields to be null again, but eclipse isn't kind to me. 
So my question is, how do I change my main_activity file with the code above to clear the edit text forms upon button press.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public boolean sexybox = false;

public void sexyBoolean(View view){ // changes the value from true to false etc

    if(sexybox == false)
        {
        sexybox = true;
        }
    else 
    {
        sexybox = false;
    }

}

/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendText(View view) {

    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    //gives me user and number to be used.
    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    EditText usernumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_number);
    String usernamestring = username.getText().toString();
    String usernumberstring = usernumber.getText().toString();
    //checks if its null fields:
    if(usernamestring.isEmpty())
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "What's your name?";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        v.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    if(usernumberstring.isEmpty())
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "What's your numbah?";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        TextView v = (TextView) toast.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        v.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }

    ///
    System.out.println("SENDING MESSAGE:");
    System.out.println(usernamestring);
    System.out.println(usernumberstring);
    String body = "Hi Jake - I'm " + usernamestring + "! I'm sending a self text so we can talk or whatever. ";
    //IF CUTE button toggled
        if(sexybox == true)
        {
            body = body + "I think you're hot too ;)";
        }

    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body); //obvi the message
    smsIntent.putExtra("address", usernumberstring); //obvi the number, replace usernumberstring
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); // guess i leave this alone
//RESET FIELDS ????
//        EditText edit_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
//        edit_name.setText("");
  //  editText.setText("");
    //editText.setText(null);

    startActivity(smsIntent);
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

// XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:text="@string/toptext"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#33B5E5"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toptext2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:text="@string/toptext2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#33B5E5" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="137dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/edit_number"
    android:inputType="phone" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/thanks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/thanks"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#33B5E5" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/sexycheckbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="sexyBoolean"
    android:text="@string/sexycheckbox" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#303030"
    android:onClick="sendText"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My app visually is here: http://imgur.com/bTGZhp1

Comment: can you show the layout XML . textView.setText(""); should work at setting your text. I am not sure what you mean about restarting , have you tried to read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: edited it to show. I don't quite get the activity lifestyle. I've seen that page and read it though tenfold.

Comment: What error do you get on your `edit_name.setText("");` ?

Comment: I'm not sure where to actually put it. In the main java file, i put it under // reset fields, and it just tells me "Editname can't be resolved .

Comment: Fine where it is, i.e at that point your text will be cleared. Eclipse causes problems sometimes on compile. Try project->clean ... project->build .... make sure you don`t have Android.R imported rather your locally generated R